# How to combine one row's data into a single cell using Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have to combine 3 cells of a row separated by "-".

**Input is:**

```
A1  A9  AMF
A2  B9  BMF 
A1  A9  AMF (Same as 1st row)
A4  D9  DMF
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
A1-A9-AMF
A2-B9-BMF
A4-D9-DMF
```

I have used the following,

```
for r1 in row:
    strcell1 = '-'.join(map(str,row)) # converting to string list
    cell1 = ''.join(strcell1)         # joining the cells
    list_value = [cell1]
    ws.append(list_value)            #writing on a different sheet of same workbook
```

But I am not getting the expected output, is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to `.join()` the `row`s together which won't work. Try instead:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_workbook.xlsx')
ws1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
combined = []
for row in ws.rows:
    combined.append('-'.join(r1.value for r1 in row))
```

Result:

```
>>> print(combined)
[u'A1-A9-AMF', u'A2-B9-BMF', u'A1-A9-AMF', u'A4-D9-DMF']
```

Write result to other sheet:

```
ws2 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet2')
for val in combined:
    ws2.append([val])
wb.save('your_workbook_modified.xlsx')
```

Comment: second line should read `ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')`.  To only join the first 3 columns change to `    combined.append('-'.join(cell.value for cell in row[:3] ))`

Comment: It worked by using "combined.append('-'.join(r1.value for r1 in row))".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped.