# Openpyxl: Appending all cell values in each row, then insert into tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm a beginner in python and stackoverflow. I have imported openpyxl and tkinter to make this:

def cell_range():

```
global combinedCells
try:
    startRange = startingCell.get()
    endRange = endingCell.get()
    for rowOfCellObjects in chosenSheet[startRange:endRange]:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            stringValues = str(cellObj.value)
        combinedCells = []
        combinedCells.append('-'.join(stringValues for r1 in rowOfCellObjects))
        listbox4.insert(END, combinedCells)

except IndexError:
    pass
```

I want to make something like this: [How to combine one row's data into a single cell using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352862/how-to-combine-one-rows-data-into-a-single-cell-using-openpyxl)

Why is my listbox displaying Addie Ramirez-Addie Ramirez, instead of 1-Addie Ramirez? I have two columns, number and name. The first column seems to be ignored.

And I did refer to this: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating a list of each cell in a row is probably what you want to do. The first link you provided shows how to do that so what is the problem? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) So we can better understand your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first post. I edited the question. Let me know if it is still vague.